# getting error while trying to open websocket connection

Tags: django, django-channels

This is the error I am getting while trying to start the websocket.

I am not able

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yana/Desktop/learn/code-executor/server/./codeexec/asgi.py", line 7, in <module>
    from collaborate.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
  File "/home/yana/Desktop/learn/code-executor/server/./collaborate/routing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collaborate import consumers
  File "/home/yana/Desktop/learn/code-executor/server/./collaborate/consumers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collaborate.models import CollaborateRoom
  File "/home/yana/Desktop/learn/code-executor/server/./collaborate/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from authentication.models import CustomUser
  File "/home/yana/Desktop/learn/code-executor/server/./authentication/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .manager import UserManager  
  File "/home/yana/Desktop/learn/code-executor/server/./authentication/manager.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I was trying to open my websocket. But I am getting errors before opening.